# Inserting distinct values from XML into database table

Tags: java, xml, oracle, xsd

**I have XML as follows:**

```
    <employee>
        <code>13</code>
        <label>Admin</label>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <code>13</code>
        <label>Admin</label>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <code>09</code>
        <label>Logistics</label>
    </employee>
```

In my Oracle database, I have 2 columns, namely CODE1, CODE2.
The data should be inserted like CODE1= 13 and CODE2= 09.

But, currently what is happening is that CODE1= 13 and CODE2= 13. And 09 is not been inserted in database.

It just stores the first 2 values ignoring the rest.
**My requirement is that, duplicate values must be inserted only once in DB**.

**Expected result:**
CODE1= 13, CODE2= 09

Following is my java code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            final int count = i + 1;
            String code = null;
            final Emploi[] employee = tabLieuTrav.getEmployee();
                code = employee[i].getCode();
                if (code != null) {
                mapParam.addParamValue(CODE + count,
                        code);
            } else {
                mapParam.addParamValue(CODE + count, null,
                        Types.VARCHAR);
            }
```

getCode() returns the value (e.g. 13) from tag .

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: how to read xml data in your program, please share the relevant source code

Comment: this is not relevant to read the xml data

Comment: isn't. how to pass above xml file into your programe, source code?

Comment: `<code>` element's value is hold in the `ecode` variable or what  is the relevant variable?

Comment: Hope now its more clear. Need to make some changes before posting in original code for security reasons...if you understand :)

Comment: any idea how can I do this @Lakshan

Comment: Please refer my answer

Answer (score 1):

try with following solutions,

firstly you should create a Employee class including with `hasCode()` and `equals()` methods as follows,

```
public class Employee {

    private int code; 
    private String lable;

    public Employee(int code, String lable) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.lable = lable;
    }
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getLable() {
        return lable;
    }
    public void setLable(String lable) {
        this.lable = lable;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + code;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (code != other.code)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

above `hasCode()` and `equals()` methods are generated by eclipse ide. you can creates these methods manually like this,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Employee) {
        return Objects.equals(code, ((Employee) obj).code);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.code;
}
```

**equals Method** : Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one. [for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

**hashCode Method** : Returns a hash code value for the object. This method is supported for the benefit of hash tables such as those provided by HashMap. [for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())

then, add `employee` array to ArrayList. because below mentioned methods describe how to get distinct values from ArrayList.

```
Emploi[] employee = tabLieuTrav.getEmployee();
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(employee));
```

then, you can use one of the following methods for remove duplicate values from ArrayList (`empList`)

method one, remove duplicates from ArrayList using Set (A collection that contains no duplicate elements) [for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

```
HashSet<Employee> uniqueEmployee = new HashSet(empList);
```

method two, remove duplicates from ArrayList using java 8 stream distinct method (return distinct element from collection) [for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--)

```
List<Employee> uniqueEmployee = empList..stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList();
```

finally, you can use `uniqueEmployee` collection as follows,

```
for (Employee employee : uniqueEmployee) {
    code = employee.getCode();
    if (code != null) {
        mapParam.addParamValue(CODE + count, code);
    } else {
        mapParam.addParamValue(CODE + count, null, Types.VARCHAR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will let you know the result